In ASCIIDOC is it possible to convert a CSV file to a set of variables?
I have a CSV list of abbreviations that I want to use in my document. Some of the abbreviations might change in the CSV file and I think it would be neat if I could use it as the source to automate variable creation instead of specifying the variables one by one in ASCIIDOC. I know that CSVs can be included easily but can the column pairs be converted into variables:



Variables
Values




VAR1
VAL1


VAR2
VAL2



I have tried looking into the matter but cannot find too much information

You'd need to write an extension

I assume that by "variable" you mean asciidoc attributes -- as in :var1: VAL2, so that you can then say Blah blah {var1} blah and have it come out as "Blah blah VAL2 blah". In that case, just use your favorite scripting language to convert the abbreviations.csv file to an attributes.adoc file, and then use include::attributes.adoc[] to pull them in.
For python the script might look like:
include re
from pathlib include Path
lines = Path('abbreviations.csv').readlines()
newlines = []
for line in lines:
    newlines.append(re.sub(r'([^,]*),(.*)',r':\1/L: \2',line)
Path('attributes.adoc').writelines(newlines)

NOTE: This is off the top of my head, untested. I probably got the /L lowercase directive wrong, for one thing, but you get the idea. Also, you might need to bring in an actual CSV parser if your CSV is quoted, or whatever.
OTOH, if you are talking about converting the CSV to a glossary of terms using the asciidoc syntax for term definitions (e.g. foo:: being foo-ish), then it's almost the exact same thing. Just change the substitution pattern to r'\1:: \2' (move the first colon and drop the lowercase directive), and then write it to a glossary.adoc file. In fact, you could do both, with two different includes, one up front for the attributes.adoc, and one at the back in an appendix for the glossary.adoc.
